# To use goroutine in for loop, why iterating over pointers to struct but not structs themselves works

Tags: pointers, for-loop, go

### Background

I'm reading 50 shades in Go, specifically [Iteration Variables and Closures in "for" Statements](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/index.html#closure_for_it_vars), and I'm going to take an excerpt from it.

#### Incorrect

```
    package main

    import (  
        "fmt"
        "time"
    )

    type field struct {  
        name string
    }

    func (p *field) print() {  
        fmt.Println(p.name)
    }

    func main() {  
        data := []field{{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}}

        for _,v := range data {
            go v.print()
        }

        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        //goroutines print: three, three, three
    }
```

#### Correct

Change `[]field{{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}}` to `[]*field{{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}}`, and `one`, `two`, and `three` will be printed in some order.

### My Thought Process

1. In the incorrect one, `go v.print()` is replaced by `go (&v).print()` by compiler because `print()` is defined on pointer receiver.
2. Until the spawned goroutine is executed, runtime only knows that goroutine should execute`print()`, but has no idea pointer of which instance should be passed as the receiver.
3. When the spawned goroutine is executed, it's highly possible that the for loop has terminated, so when we want to decide which value should be passed as the receiver, we get the address of `v`, which is shared during the entire loop and updated in each iteration, so we pass the address of the last element of `data` as the receiver to `print()`, and that's why we get 3 `three` printed.

### Problem

To me, changing `[]field` to `[]*field` only lets compiler skip the step 1, but does not change step 2 and step 3, so I don't know why that fixes the problem.

I guess there must be some flaws in my thought process, and I appreciate any advice.

### Update

I happened to see another correct implementation [here](http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/#comment-3338317553), and I think I might know where went wrong in my thought process.

```
data := []field{{"one"}, {"two"}, {"three"}}

for i := range data {
    go data[i].print()
}
```

The thing is, the pointer to be passed to `print()` as the receiver, is determined in step 2 instead of step 3. That means in the incorrect version, we're passing the same address in each iteration, but the content it points to  (`data`) is updated in each iteration. However, in the correct version, the pointers being passed to `print()` as the receiver, point to the actual elements of `field`. The same applies to the case using indices.

Comment: Your reasoning is too complex, the problem is much simpler. In the `for` loop there is just one variable `v` for **each** loop iteration: The variable v is _reused_ for each and every iteration, only its value is updated. A single variable has a single address, so the address is the same for each iteration. So all goroutines are spawned with the same address. Once they start working the will work on the same address, this happens very likely after terminating the for loop, so all will work in the last element. See https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: @Volker Thank you for providing the link, it's kind of  embarrassing that later on I figured it out why the correct version works. Could you check my **Update** block?

Comment: There are more ways to fix the incorrect version. Using a slice of pointers is just one way. Two other ways are describes in the link to the FAQ entry (and I think these are the better solutions). I'd recommend to read all the official documentation first before diving into some arbitrary blog post. Take the Tour of Go, read Effective Go, read the whole FAQ, then the language spec, then the blog post on "array and slices", "strings, bytes and runes", and the "concurrency patterns". And then do this all once more.

Comment: Yes, the "Update" is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your receiver is a poniter and you have to define your field slice as pointer this is why this code works

```
data := []*field{{"one"}, {"two"}, {"three"}}
```

if you change your receiver to non pointer you code works too .

```
func (p field) print() {
    fmt.Println(p.name)
}

data := []field{{"one"}, {"two"}, {"three"}}
```